# Pegar IP interno via Python (Roteador)

Tags: python, linux, redes, internet

Tô a um bom tempinho fazendo pesquisas sobre isso, e queria saber como pegar o ip local (obviamente) do meu roteador em python num ambiente Linux, procurei isso no Google diversas vezes e sempre me vinham com

```
hostname = socket.gethostname
ip = gethostbyname(hostname)
```

Isso aqui retorna em 127.0.0.1
Definitivamente eu não quero isso, na verdade o que eu busco é guardar o ip do roteador (aqui é 192.168.0.1) numa variável

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Windows, você pode conseguir usando o `netifaces`, você pode instalar ele pelo **pip** e vai precisar do **[Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/visual-cpp-build-tools/)**:

```
import netifaces

gateways = netifaces.gateways()
gateway_padrao = gateways['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][0]
print(gateway_padrao)
```

Comment: Assumo que foi meu erro não adicionar essa informação, mas quero fazer isso em um ambiente Linux

Comment: Acho que essa resposta pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6556951/14100521

Answer (score 0):

Crie um processo subjacente com a classe [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) para executar a linha de comando:

```
$ hostname -I
```

Use o método [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) para retornar STDOUT.

```
import subprocess

#O argumento stdout=subprocess.PIPE que informa Popen deve abrir um Pipe para STDOUT.
#O argumento stderr=subprocess.STDOUT que informa Popen redirecionar STDERR para STDOUT.
out = subprocess.Popen(['hostname', '-I'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
stdout,_ = out.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Depois de um tempo de estudo cheguei a uma resolução final**:

```
ip = os.popen("ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{printf $3}'").read().strip()
```

**Funciona para Linux, cabeado e Wi-Fi.**